# how to define a module pattern for an array of products with products properties?

Tags: javascript

The webpage I'm developing loads some product information of a varying number of products from  the database. I'd like to save this product info in a module pattern (simulating static variables) so it can be used by various javascript functions on the webpage. Each productitem has a (same) number (and same type) of product properties such as 'name', 'type' and 'price'. At the moment I use the structure as illustrated in the simplified example below. This structure uses various arrays, one for each product product property, but I was wondering how  to define a more elegant (clearer) structure with an array of products and productproperties per array element? I read a lot on this site and other pages about defining javascript arrays and defining module patterns, but still couldnt figure this out...

```
module = function(){
 var name = [],
     price = [],
     type = [];

 var init = function(){ // initialises the productproperties of all products; to be elaborated later
 };

 return{init:init}
}();
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected input and desired output?

Comment: The expected output would be something like [{name:"Volvo",price:"67000",type:"automatic"},{name:"Mercedes",price:"77000",type:"manual"}]; Function Init(msg) would set the values in the module with var msg being the jason encoded output from a php file that retrieves the values from the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on what you want to do with that products..
but i think most logical solution would be use something like `var products = [{name:'', price:'', type:''}];` if you do so, then manipulation more easier than with arrays.. or you can use `product` and `products` modules.

Comment: excellent, thnx (!) I tried something like yours in jsfiddle but did not have the syntax right...