# how to define a module pattern for an array of products with products properties (part 2)?

Tags: javascript

I asked this question before (see [how to define a module pattern for an array of products with products properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808411/how-to-define-a-module-pattern-for-an-array-of-products-with-products-properties)) and believed i got the right answer. But I was a bit early to approve the suggestion; when I tested a bit more (with jsfiddle) the suggested solution does not work unfortenately for all array elements, see simplified example below:

```
var products = [{name:'', price:'', type:''}]; //solution given

//this works, e.g. for first array element
products[0].name = 'aname';
alert(products[0].name);

// this does not work, e.g. for following array elements
products[1].name = 'aname';
alert(products[1].name); //no response in jsfiddle
```

My question again: how to define up an elegant structure with a resulting output such as?: [{name:"Volvo",price:"67000",type:"automatic"},{name:"Mercedes",price:"77000",ty‌​pe:"manual"}];

Note the number of array elements can vary. Also note that a solution like below would work but this is only useful when the number of array elements is known when defining, which is not the case in my situation...

```
var products = [{name:'', price:'', type:''},{name:'', price:'', type:''}]; //solution will work for 2 array elements
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when you try to access `products[1]` it hasn't been instantiated yet. So it's 'undefined'. I created a function that checks if there's a value for the given key, and creates a default value if there's none. You then access your array using the function. This is just one of multiple options you have for 'auto-creating' array values on access:

```
var products = []; 

function getProduct(x){
    // Check if array key exists. If not, create it
    if(typeof products[x] === "undefined")
        products[x] = {name:'', price:'', type:''};
    return products[x];
}


getProduct(0).name = 'aname';
alert(getProduct(0).name);

getProduct(1).name = 'aname2';
alert(getProduct(1).name);
```